# Regex find catch blocks without log

Tags: regex, powergrep

I am using regex with PowerGrep to search through a bunch of files. I am working with java files and my goal is to find all catch [blocks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html) that do not contain the word `log` within the block so that I can add logging. There are alot of files, so going through them manually isn't really feasible.

Examples of what **should** be found

```
catch (Exception e) {
    //comment#
    int math = 1 +2 * (3);
    String email = "email@example.com";
    anothermethod.call();
    //no logging
}
```

and

```
catch(AnotherException e ) {}    //no logging
```

Examples of what **should NOT** be found

```
catch(AnotherException e ) {  
     //some code
     log.error("Error message");
     //some more code 
}
```

and

```
catch(BadE_xception e) { log.error(e); }
```

I am not very experienced with regex, but this is what I have so far:

start of catch block: `catch\s*\(\s*\w*\s+\w*\s*\)\s*\{.*?`

but then I am not sure where to go from there to specify not contain `log`. If you have ideas on how to do this without regex, that works perfect for me as well. Thanks

Comment: There probably can be nested braces within the `catch` blocks, right? PowerGREP's regex engine can't handle recursion (yet).

Comment: Yeah, there are those cases. Since logging isn't absolutely essential, I'm willing to overlook those right now and just get the non-nested cases.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get a finite level of nested cases, at least.

For the no-nested case, modifying the end of your expression:

```
catch\s*\(\s*\w*\s+\w*\s*\)\s*\{(?:[^}](?!\blog\b))*\}
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Let's break this down.

1. We're strictly looking at non-`}` characters; hence `[^}]`. Once we find the first `}`, we're done.
2. The `(?!foo)` is called a *negative lookahead assertion*. It means, "This point is *not* followed by `foo`."
3. The `\b` is a word-boundary. Surrounding `log` in `\b`s ensures that we don't catch "false positives" like "clog" and "logical". You want the sole word, "log".
4. The `(?:foo)` is a way to group an expression without capturing. This isn't important—for now pretend it's the same as `(foo)`. Its purpose is so that the whole group can be quantified by the `*`.
5. Putting it all together: we are checking character by character, each one *not* being a `}`, and each one *not* being followed by the whole word, `log`.

That ensures that the word `log` is nowhere within the non-nested catch block.

Now, moving onto the nested cases. As @TimPietzcker pointed out, PowerGREP doesn't support recursive expressions yet, but for your purposes you may be satisfied with a *finite* number of nestings. Here's the expression for *one* level of nesting:

```
catch\s*\(\s*\w*\s+\w*\s*\)\s*\{(?:[^{}](?!\blog\b)|\{(?:[^}](?!\blog\b))*\})*\}
                                     ^             ^========================
```

We've added the `{` character to the class of characters we don't like. This is because if we encounter this character, we want to switch over via alternation (`|`) to the nested case, which, as you can see by comparing the part underlined by `=` signs, is an exact copy of the original "inner" expression. You can continue to nest this way as much as you'd like, to capture an arbitrary number of balanced nestings.

---

Here's the template for 10 levels of nesting, which should be sufficient for most applications of this sort.

```
catch\s*\(\s*\w*\s+\w*\s*\)\s*\{(?:SEED|\{(?:SEED|\{(?:SEED|\{(?:SEED|\{(?:SEED|\{(?:SEED|\{(?:SEED|\{(?:SEED|\{(?:SEED|\{(?:SEED|\{(?:SEED)*\})*\})*\})*\})*\})*\})*\})*\})*\})*\})*\}
```

where `SEED` is the recursion seed, `[^{}](?!\blog\b)`. I've written it this way so it's visually easier to remove or add recursions as desired. Expanded, the above becomes:

```
catch\s*\(\s*\w*\s+\w*\s*\)\s*\{(?:[^{}](?!\blog\b)|\{(?:[^{}](?!\blog\b)|\{(?:[^{}](?!\blog\b)|\{(?:[^{}](?!\blog\b)|\{(?:[^{}](?!\blog\b)|\{(?:[^{}](?!\blog\b)|\{(?:[^{}](?!\blog\b)|\{(?:[^{}](?!\blog\b)|\{(?:[^{}](?!\blog\b)|\{(?:[^{}](?!\blog\b)|\{(?:[^{}](?!\blog\b))*\})*\})*\})*\})*\})*\})*\})*\})*\})*\})*\}
```

Comment: No problem. Also edited in an expression for 10 levels of nesting, for the convenience of future viewers.

Comment: Doesn't work for exceptions declared final, as stated, so a little tweak is in order. Myself added an \s*\w* after the catch opening bracket, but I'm not an regexp guru.